# Telerik Reports Top N Records are incorrectly displaying

Tags: telerik, report, telerik-reporting

I am designing a Telerik report. My data source contains 33 records for a single date (say 01-May-2023). When I choose to select top 20 records, I expect that all 20 records should be of the same date but somehow its not happening. I am applying filter Top N = 20 in filters. I am using Standalone Telerik report designer and unable to find why its happening. If I remove the filter and choose to show all the records it works perfectly fine but the problem is I want to show only top 20 records which is now working correctly. Any ideas what could be the problem?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is a problem with the **TOP N** operator when working with **DateTime** values in **Telerik Reporting**. Interestingly, the *TOP %* operator filters correctly and shows the correct proportion of the values, or more if there are items in the sorted list with the same value.

The problem is logged as a bug - [Operator TOP N with DateTime value for the filtering Expression sorts the dataset but returns all data records instead of top N only](https://feedback.telerik.com/reporting/1607515-operator-top-n-with-datetime-value-for-the-filtering-expression-sorts-the-dataset-but-returns-all-data-records-instead-of-top-n-only). The workaround is also explained there, with a demo report attached.

Briefly, you may apply two filtering rules as seen on the [linked screenshot](https://screenpal.com/i/c0hellVzH1s). The first filter is the normal one that you should use to get only the TOP 5 of the field values. It sorts the data set but doesn't select the top 5 records. The second filter is with empty *Expression* and its purpose is to return the required number of records.